# Resource Manager: How to get list of app ids that were executed in a given job queue

Tags: hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I want to get a list of YARN app ids that were executed in a MapReduce job queue.

I explored [Resource Manager API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html) but could not find an API which simply requires me to pass job queue name and get the list of app ids.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Resource Manager `Cluster Applications API` accepts `queue` as parameter for filtering.  However, this API will only show you current jobs.  For jobs that have completed you need to look at the Job History server.  The Job History Server's `Jobs API` shows completed jobs and also supports `queue` as a parameter for filtering.

```
curl JOB_HIST_URL/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs?queue=QUEUENAME
```

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/HistoryServerRest.html#Jobs_API